# Can a DLQ be configured to send an email notification?

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jmx

I'm trying to find a way to send an email out to a sysAdmin to notify them that something's gone wrong with their routes and the DLQ is filling-up.

I'm working on a legacy system comprising the following components/versions:

- Camel (v5.5.1)
- ActiveMQ (v2.8.5)

Unfortunately the system owners are adamant they shall not be upgrading to current versions.

I've got two routes defined in the `camel-context.xml` file (each with their own DLQ), one of which is here...

```
<camelContext id="Bob-to-John" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <jmxAgent id="agent" createConnector="true" registryPort="3333"/>

<!-- EXCEPTION HANDLING -->

<onException>
  <exception>org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException</exception>
  <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="5"/>
  <handled> <constant>true</constant> </handled>
</onException>

<onException>
  <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>
  <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0"/>
  <handled> <constant>true</constant> </handled>
</onException>

<!-- ROUTES -->

<route id="fromBob" autoStartup="true" errorHandlerRef="bobsDeadLetterErrorHandler" >
  <!-- get data from Apache ActiveMQ -->
  <from uri="mina:tcp://0.0.0.0:100?textline=true&amp;disconnect=true&amp;textlineDelimiter=UNIX&amp;decoderMaxLineLength=1048576&amp;encoding=UTF-8" />

  <!-- make sure data is transferred in UTF-8 format -->
  <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" />

  <!-- attempt to validate against Bob's XML schema -->
  <to uri="validator:http://localhost/xsd/input.BOB.xsd" />

  <!-- Bob to John transformation -->
  <to uri="xslt:file:///home/xsl/bobToJohn.xsl" />

  <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod"> <constant>POST</constant> </setHeader>

  <!-- send to John -->
  <inOut uri="activemq:input.JOHN" />
</route>

<!-- DEAD LETTER CHANNELS -->

<bean id="bobsDeadLetterErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
  <!-- exchanges are routed to activemq:failure.BOB in case redelivery failed -->
  <property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:failure.BOB"/>
  <!-- reference the redelivery policy to use -->
  <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
</bean>


<!-- lets configure the default ActiveMQ broker URL -->
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&amp;broker.useJmx=false"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- configure the camel activemq component to use the current broker -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
      <property name="userName" value="blahblah" />
      <property name="password" value="ENC(mYRkg+4Quhua1kvpCCI2hg==)" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- Creating mina endpoints is a bit complex so we reuse MinaComponnet
     as a factory bean to create our endpoint, this is the easiest to do -->
<bean id="mina" class="org.apache.camel.component.mina.MinaComponent">
  <!-- we must provide a camel context so we refer to it by its id -->
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="BOB-to-JOHN" />
</bean>
```

Is there something I can add to the DLQ to send this notification out, or is this only possible with more current versions of this stuff? Or am I looking in completely the wrong place altogether?!

I've also got them looking at using hawt.io to manage stuff, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no support for that even in the latest version of ActiveMQ.  As I see it you have two options here.

1. Create a custom broker plugin that sends an email when it sees a message being sent into the DLQ, you'd probably need access to the broker to add additional dependencies and of course install the plugin.
2. Create a Camel route that reads from the DLQ and sends an email for each message it receives.  In this case if you wanted to preserve the messages in the DLQ the Camel route would need to again send them back into the Queue.  This of course could have unintended side effects so testing would be a good idea.

Comment: Wow, seems strange that this sort of thing isn't there by default. I'd have thought this would be extremely useful...